# Why are ALL TypeScript files in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project being compiled in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise when I save a single one?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2022

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 project that I edit and build with Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise (v17.5.5, ARM build) on a Windows 11 on ARM PC. This project uses the following line in its `packages.config` file to include TypeScript:

```
<package id="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" version="4.8.4" targetFramework="net48" developmentDependency="true" />
```

When I edit TS files within this project and save them, they are auto-compiled as they should be, but this *sometimes* triggers a recompile of the *entire* project, which is a complete waste of time and computer resources.

What's even worse, is that the TS files that haven't changed are compiled differently every time, so that I'm left with several files marked by Git as having been changed, even though the only differences are inconsequential (class constructors moved, minified variables renamed, etc.).

How can I update the VS settings so that this nonsense doesn't happen anymore? I only want TS files that have **actually changed** to be compiled on save; everything else should be left the heck alone!

MTIA :-)

Comment: Don't put your build artifacts in source control. The JavaScript output by TSC is not source code

Comment: @AluanHaddad My team and I use Azure DevOps to deploy this project to many environments and clients, so setting that up to build the TS files on deploy would be a pain. And an even bigger pain would be sorting through the many JS files in the project, keeping the really old ones that aren't TS-backed, and deleting the others. Sure, we could probably automate this with a script of some sort, and maybe we should, but I don't really want to affect my colleagues who aren't having this issue. Isn't there **some** way to do what I've asked?? It seems like it should be default behaviour to me!

Comment: No there isn't an easy way of handling this. It sounds like you need to reorganize your code base. It's also perfectly possible to do this with azure devops. I've done it.

Comment: I do realize it would be a big change, but relying on the IDE to handle your compilation based on file saves is simply not a reliable way to deploy anyway

Comment: "...simply not a reliable way to deploy anyway" - Yeah I suppose you're right. I'll bring it up with the team tomorrow morning, but I doubt they'll be very receptive to the idea :-( Oh well, I guess I'll just have to live with it. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: No problem and good luck to you and your team.